# JavaApplet when you press a button/ click on image

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to run JavaApplet when you press a button , or when you click on the image on the webpage?

Maybe you guys can share any example, related html/jscript/jquery?

What is wrong with my code at this point?

```
<html> 
    <script> 
        function openApplet(){ 
        var attributes = {codebase:'.', 
        code:'d.Applet', 
        archive:'Applet.jar', 
        WIDTH=500, HEIGHT=300} ; 
    } 
    </script> 
    <body> 
        <applet id="myapplet" 
         CODEBASE="." 
         ARCHIVE="Applet.jar" 
         CODE="d.Applet" 
         WIDTH=500 HEIGHT=300 
         style="visibility:hidden;" 
        > 
        </applet> 
        <input value="Applet_on_Click" onclick="openApplet()" type="button"> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

I'm just looking for very simple solution. Click on the image , applet shows up, click on the different image , another applet will show up. Or maybe these things can happen when we press a button too?

**Update**

Thank you **slowpoison** for the information!

But I'm missing something.

There is my original code now:

http://www.text-upload.com/read.php?id=360320&c=7544773

This is working just with pure html. But there is no action when you click on the button.
If I disable this row "style="visibility:hidden" , applet will show up without a click.

I wan't to show applet just after the button click. :(

Comment: What does the applet do?

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `applet` tag to the document in the `onclick` handler.

```
var applet = document.createElement("applet");
// fill in various attributes for applet
// ...

// "install" the applet
document.getElementById("appletContainer").appendChild(applet);
```